# Should one put a comma after an explaining phrase?

Tags: punctuation, comma, apposition

> Ich habe eine Frage, die den Gott, den Grund für alles betrifft.

I hope that this sentence may be translated as:

> I have a  question that concerns the God, the reason of everything.

The phrase *den Grund für alles* explains the meaning of *den Gott*; so should one put a comma after *den Grund für alles* and before the verb?

Comment: Just a side note: we would not use an article with *Gott*.

Comment: @Takkat, well, that depends. „Ich habe gehört, dass Deine Religion einen Gott, einen Teufel und noch so manch mehr Übernatürliches enthält. Ich habe eine Frage, die den Gott betrifft.“

Comment: "Just a side note: we would not use an article with Gott" Oh my God!

Comment: Actually I do find it extremely odd to use an article in the sentence above. From all what I know it should read "Ich habe eine Frage, die Gott betrifft". In case that had changed recently I'd be interested to learn more: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24637/where-dont-we-use-an-article-with-god

Comment: I have the feeling that the article for *God* in the English version is wrong too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, indeed; so-called appositions are enclosed by commas.