# Where don't we use an article with God

Tags: article

From comments on a [recent question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24632/should-one-put-a-comma-after-an-explaining-phrase) where I commented that in the sentence given there:

> Ich habe eine Frage, die den Gott betrifft.

we usually would not use an article with God. There was considerable dispute on that. My comment there even received a rude/offensive flag.

This makes me wonder if I was correct in my notion that we do not use an article when talking about God in sentences like the one above, and in other sentences like for example:

> Ich habe eine Frage, die Gott betrifft.
>   Lass uns über Gott reden.
>   Nur Gott weiß, was hier geschehen ist.
>   Keiner steht über Gott.

A search on Google did not reveal many result where people used an article in similar sentences. Are there any rules, or reasons why the article is usually not used here? When is using an article allowed?

Comment: In my region, when *talking* about God we normally use an article; but then again we even use an article when talking about Stefan or Thomas. ;-)

Comment: Well, this is based on general nitpicking. You say, we don't use an article with "Gott". What you didn't explicitly say is that you referred to that very example and similar use cases. But obviously, there are other use cases where everyone, including you, would add an article before "Gott". So let's do some nitpicking. Die Höhner sing "Der liebe Gott weiß, dass ich kein Engel bin". So, you were wrong! – No, actually, you weren't wrong but you weren't clear enough in your comment. And properly speaking, you all are right.

Comment: @Em1: what but the sentence in the question would I have commented upon? Comments are not for general wisdom but for single issues in a post. Your example is quite interesting, as it may point to an answer. We do say "der liebe Gott", "der allmächtige Gott", etc. but  your example would be odd without the adjective "Der Gott weiß, dass ich kein Engel bin".

Comment: Has that considerable dispute been deleted? I don't see it. And I did not *really* disagree. For example, Christians usually refer to their God without an article.

Comment: Interestingly, we say "Gott (without article), der HERR (always with article)".

Comment: You use an article when you refer to a specific aspect of god, of course: _der allmächtige, der güte, der ewige, der barmherzige Gott. Der Gott des Alten Testaments ..._ The same is true when you talk about "a" god, especially one you don't yourself believe in: _der Gott der kleinen Dinge_.  I don't think it's all that different from English, actually.

Comment: @Ingmar: Not necessarily. When "Gott" is used like a name, there won't be an article, even when referring to a specific aspect. "Allmächtiger Gott, barmherziger Gott! Gott des Alten Testaments, ich spreche zu dir! Lieber Ingmar, freundlicher Ingmar! Ingmar aus *German Stack Exchange*, ich spreche zu dir!"

Comment: Maybe you are not so familiar with German classical literature. In "Nathan der Weise" by Lessing, you find bothe uses of the word, with and without article.

Comment: @Karl: interesting! You should back this up with quotes e.g. in an own answer, otherwise I consider this comment as plain wrong and misleading.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

My perception as a native speaker of German is that "Gott" can be used as a normal noun (in that case, it appears with an article), or like a name (in that case, it appears without an article).

The usage as a name is quite apparent in all contexts where the exclusive existence of a single god is assumed. In German-speaking cultures, this currently often refers to the Christian god.

The usage as a noun, on the other hand, is easier to find when looking for contexts that assume more than one deity. This is most obviously the case in texts about the mythology of various polytheistic cultures.

As a small example, the (completely made-up) sentence "Osiris traf einen Menschen und sang ein Lied." could be broken up to "Osiris traf einen Menschen. Der Gott sang ein Lied." Using "Gott" without an article here, "Osiris traf einen Menschen. Gott sang ein Lied.", would change the meaning (and actually, it would sound as if there are three protagonists in this small story - Osiris (an Egyptian god), a human, and another character whose name is "Gott", coming back to using "Gott" as a name).

EDIT: Of course, the one assumed entity named "Gott" could just as well be refered to as "der Gott". However, given that the applied designation "Gott" coincides with the descriptive noun "der Gott", this could make such texts quite confusing and also cause them to sound unintentionally funny - e.g. "Gott, der Gott". As mentioned by [Matthias](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/9091/matthias) in a comment, a kind of a workaround is sometimes chosen by keeping "Gott" as a name while using another descriptive noun: "Gott, der Herr". Once again, if a different name for the god being mentioned can be used, the workaround appears much less necessary - "Osiris, der Gott" sounds completely fine, as does "Aton, der Gott".

Comment: Actually, no need to make up sentences. [Just read the Bible](http://www.bibel-online.net/suche/?qs=%22der+gott%22). The distinction between name and noun is very helpful. +1

Comment: @Matthias: Almost all of the occurrences of "der Gott" in that text are further qualified (e.g. "der Gott Abrahams"), which can blur the issue. At least, I would expect some people to counter that "fine, so 'der Gott' can be used *if and only if* it is followed with a genitive, but 'der Gott' on its own still cannot be used". Hence my made-up sentence :)

Comment: Thinking of it - the rules are the same as for [people's names](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15369/using-definite-article-with-peoples-names). Omitting the article with "Gott" may be a Chrisitian's work aound for God being nameless. This is even better reflected in English, when [God used as a name is being capitalized](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3139/when-should-the-word-god-be-capitalized) but the noun *god* isn't.

Comment: Christen haben ein persönliches Verhältnis zu ihrem Gott, sie duzen ihn sogar. Ein Artikel macht sich in einer Anrede nicht gut.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: Ja, wie ich in meiner Antwort erläutert habe, wird "Gott" als Name verwendet, wobei dann der Artikel entfällt. Mir fällt jetzt eigentlich auch kein Beispiel aus einer anderen Religion (deren Texte ins Deutsche übertragen wurden) ein, in der eine Gottheit (zumindest in der Übersetzung) nicht geduzt wird - "Ich bitte Sie um Vergebung, <Name des Gottes>." scheint mir jedenfalls generell recht unnatürlich zu klingen.

Answer (score 16):

<sup>This answer goes along the same lines as [O. R. Mapper’s](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/24638/2594), but is too much for comments.</sup>

If you so wish, the word *Gott* can have two meanings (see also the [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Gott)):

- ***God*** – the single god in a monotheistic weltanschauung. This word behaves like a name.
- ***god*** – some supernatural entity. This word behaves like a regular substantive.

*Gott* in the second meaning always goes with an article. *Gott* in the first meaning goes with an article, when a normal name would do the same (even in regions where you do not generally use articles with names). Compare:

> Gott schenkte mir einen Stein.
> Erna schenkte mir einen Stein.
>
> Der liebe Gott schenkte uns diesen Stein.
> Die liebe Erna schenkte mir diesen Stein.
>
> Gott, der allmächtig ist, schenkte mir diesen Stein.
> Erna, die lieb ist, schenkte mir diesen Stein.
>
> Allmächtiger Gott, bitte verwandle meine Feinde in Salzsäulen.
> Liebe Erna, schicke mir bitte ein Pfund Salz.

Things become somewhat fuzzy in Bible translations (and other ancient texts) as the original texts use more words for *Gott* than the German language has and some parts were written with a polytheistic world view (in particular in the Old Testament). Moreover, most Bible translations use archaic language. Due to this and because all English translations I sampled capitalise *God* rather than not, the trick implied above that the English *God* translates to the name does not necessarily work anymore in such a context.

---

As a sidenote, *Herr* (when used to refer to the monotheistic god) behaves like a title. As with most titles, there is only one relevant holder in most contexts and thus no further specification is needed. Compare:

> Der Herr schenkte mir einen Stein.
> Der Chef schenkte mir einen Stein.
>
> Herr, bitte verwandle meine Feinde in Salzsäulen.
> Chef, schicke mir bitte ein Pfund Salz.

Answer (score 4):

Es stimmt, dass „Gott“ häufig ohne Artikel verwendet wird, wenn nicht zum Beispiel das Vorhandensein eines Adjektivs grammatikalisch einen Artikel erfordert.

Vergleichen wir die folgenden Sätze. Nehmen wir an, zwei proper gekleidete Menschen kommen auf einen zu und sagen:

> Wir möchten mit Ihnen über einen Gott sprechen.
>
> Wir möchten mit Ihnen über den Gott sprechen.
>
> Wir möchten mit Ihnen über Gott sprechen.

Der erste Satz weckt Interesse. Es geht um einen noch nicht weiter bestimmten Gott, es könnte sich im Gespräch herausstellen, um welchen.

Der zweite Satz verwirrt. Es geht anscheinend um einen bestimmten, aber der Kontext, der angibt, um welchen, ist nicht hergestellt worden.

Der dritte Satz ist rüde. Gott wird einem Namen gleich verwendet; die Sprecher setzen voraus, dass dies sinnvoll ist, da dieser Name sich auf ein existentes, wenn auch vielleicht „höheres“, Wesen bezieht, und implizieren, dass zwischen ihnen und mir darüber ein grundsätzliches Einverständnis besteht, auch darüber, was dieses Wesen sei.

Das letzte Beispiel zeigt aber auch, warum in einer Sprache, die lange Zeit von einer religiös homogenen (wenn man von Kriegen zwischen verschiedenen Konfessionen absieht) Gesellschaft gesprochen wurde, oder einer, in der man sich zumindest nathansch darauf verständigt hatte, dass die häufigsten Ausnahmen dennoch an denselben Gott glauben, das Wort „Gott“ häufig ohne Artikel benutzt wird.

Comment: "implizieren dass ... ein grundsätzliches Einverständnis besteht" - sehe ich nicht so. Sie kommunizieren lediglich, dass für sie "Gott" ein eindeutiger Name für irgendwas ist, und lassen mir jegliche Freiheit zu antworten: "Welchen?", "Ich kenne keinen Gott" oder "Wer ist das"? (Die letzte Option wäre ihnen vermutlich sogar ziemlich recht als Einstieg ins Gespräch, falls Du die gleichen adrett gekleideten Menschen meinst wie ich.)

Comment: Matthias, ich möchte mit Dir über die Partei sprechen!