# How do I translate "God" and "god" to German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, single-word-request

Naively, both (monoteistic and pagan) would be "der Gott". In Russian language the God and a god are also often discrimitated by capitalisation. How does it go in German?

Answers to the related question [Where don't we use an article with God](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24637/where-dont-we-use-an-article-with-god) employ both cases in examples, but do not specifically address the difference.

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24637/where-dont-we-use-an-article-with-god/24639

Comment: @CarstenS, Yes, I have looked at [that answer](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/24639/2279).

Comment: For example, imagine a fiction story with both gods and the God, or a priest persuading to drop gods and idols and believe in God instead.

Comment: What is the difference that capitalization makes in Russian? That should be stated in the question.

Comment: @c.p., I assume the same as in English - abrahamic God versus just a powerful enough creature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In German, the same word, namely *Gott*, is used for gods that you believe in and those that you do not believe in. However, a Christian will also use *Gott* as a name without article when referring to his god, while using an indefinite article or specifying the exact god that he is talking about when talking about other gods.

Comment: So some word plays in written texts based on this may be untranslatable to German?

Comment: I don't know, can you imagine one that works in written English but not in spoken English?

Comment: It works the same way with other proper nouns, uhm, I mean Proper Nouns ;-) In my network technologies classes ("Telematik-Vorlesungen"), we would say "ein Internet" (internet, a network comprised of many smaller independent networks) and "das Internet" (Internet, the largest, most well-known of the internets), for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try, for instance, for *god* and *бог*

> „Gott“

For any noun shall be capitalized. Not to be confused with

> Gott

Comment: Placing the word in quotes kind of ridicules or diminishes the word, as if the "quoted" god is not a "real" or full blown god in the eyes of the writer. No capitalisation _god_ is fully neutral.

Comment: This would only create confusion.

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu That's precisely what is asked above. The OP was not clear in his intention either.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm just not reading this into the question. That interpretation assumes that no capitalisation _gods_ by default are less worthy than the capital G _God_. I don't know how the nuances are laid out between the russian variants, but in the given english intermediary, this distinction in value is _not_ made from a language perspective.